# GNU Emacs: How to disable prompt to save modified buffer on exit

Tags: emacs, save, elisp

In GNU Emacs I have a particular buffer `*my-special-buffer*` which I create as the output of running a sub-process and storing the output.  I mark this buffer as read only after filling the contents.  Occasionally when I try to exit Emacs I notice that I am prompted to save this buffer:

`Save file /foo/bar/.../*my-special-buffer*? (y, n, !, ...`

Is there a buffer local variable I can set as part of the initialization of this buffer to prevent the save prompt from interrupting my attempt to shut down Emacs?  Just to be clear, I don't want to save this buffer; the buffer's purpose is only to show read-only data from the sub-process.

Comment: why can't you save the buffer when you "mark this buffer as read only after filling the contents"?

Comment: I edited to clarify that I don't want the buffer saved.

Comment: I don't think emacs should ask that unless the buffer is visiting a file. You haven't inadvertently saved it some time mid-processing?

Comment: Because of application-specific requirements,  I do assign the buffer a visited filename.  But no, I do not ever save the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is what I should set after filling in the buffer.

```
(set-buffer-modified-p nil)
```

More details [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Modification.html).  After that, I make the buffer read only.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save all buffers when exiting without any questions at all, do <kbd>C-u C-x C-c</kbd>:

> C-x C-c runs the command save-buffers-kill-terminal...
>
> ...With prefix ARG, silently save all file-visiting buffers, then kill.

If you want Emacs to think that the buffer should not be saved at all, all you need to do is to [mark it as unmodified](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Modification.html): <kbd>M-~</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not my goal to save this buffer.  I just want it ignored when I shut down emacs.